# How to reshape sparse matrices in Eigen?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, reshape, eigen

I would like to know if there is a function or an optimized way to reshape sparse matrices in Eigen.

In the documentation there is no reshape method for such matrices, so I implemented a function myself, but I don't know if it is optimized (i need it to be as fast as possible). Here is my approach:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> reshape_sp(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& x,
    lint a, lint b) {
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> y(a, b);
    for (int k=0; k<x.outerSize(); ++k) {
        for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(x,k); it; ++it) {
            int pos = it.col()*x.rows()+it.row();
            int col = int(pos/a);
            int row = pos%a;
            y.insert(row, col) = it.value();
        }
    }
    y.makeCompressed();
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of values in the matrix? Are they randomly scattered or maybe clustered together? Because then you could avoid some divisions. Speaking of which: if ```lint``` is 64 bit, you may want to change to ```col = pos / int(a)``` (same with row) because 32 bit division is faster and you are likely choking on that instruction

Comment: On the other hand, your ```pos``` calculation can easily overflow on very large sparse matrices, e.g. 100,000 x 100,000. I guess you know that you stay in signed integer range for ```rows * cols```?

Answer (score 1):

For performance, it is absolutely crucial that you call `reserve` on your matrix. I've tested with a 100,000 x 100,000 matrix population 1%. Your version (after fixing the 32 bit overflow in `pos` computation), took 3 minutes. This fixed version a few seconds:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>
reshape(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& orig,
    int rows, int cols)
{
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> rtrn(rows, cols);
  rtrn.reserve(orig.nonZeros());
  using InnerIterator = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator;
  for(int k = 0; k < orig.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for(InnerIterator it(orig, k); it; ++it) {
      std::int64_t pos = std::int64_t(it.col()) * orig.rows() + it.row();
      int col = int(pos / rows);
      int row = int(pos % rows);
      rtrn.insert(row, col) = it.value();
    }
  }
  rtrn.makeCompressed();
  return rtrn;
}
```

An alternative is to work with triplets again. This is a bit slower but less likely to explode in your face the same way `insert` does. This is particularly helpful for more complex operations like transposing where you cannot guarantee that the insert appends at the end.

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>
reshape(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& orig,
        int rows, int cols)
{
  using InnerIterator = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator;
  using Triplet = Eigen::Triplet<double>;
  std::vector<Triplet> triplets;
  triplets.reserve(std::size_t(orig.nonZeros()));
  for(int k = 0; k < orig.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for(InnerIterator it(orig, k); it; ++it) {
      std::int64_t pos = std::int64_t(it.col()) * orig.rows() + it.row();
      int col = int(pos / rows);
      int row = int(pos % rows);
      triplets.emplace_back(row, col, it.value());
    }
  }
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> rtrn(rows, cols);
  rtrn.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());
  return rtrn;
}
```

Things I tested that did not work:

1. Using [FXDiv](https://github.com/Maratyszcza/FXdiv) to replace the division with a cheaper operation
2. Computing maximum distance from one index to the next within a single column to skip dividing if both values are in the same output column (may still be worth it for sparse matrices with suitable inner structure)
3. Parallelizing the loop with OpenMP, using a final `std::sort(std::execution::par, ...)` for the triplets.